# ¿En SQL Server mediante consultas existe alguna forma de mostrar varias veces aquellos registros que tengan cierto valor en un campo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero que aparezcan registros duplicados en aquellos que tengan valor superior a 1 en el campo de unidades. Pasar de esto:

| Cód. art | Cód. color | Talla | Unidades |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48310S.0 | 400 | M | 1 |
| 48310S.0 | 400 | L | 1 |
| 48318P.0 | 500 | M | 1 |
| 48318P.0 | 500 | L | 1 |
| 48318P.0 | 500 | XL | 1 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | M | 2 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | L | 2 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | XL | 1 |

A esto:

| Cód. art | Cód. color | Talla | Unidades |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48310S.0 | 400 | M | 1 |
| 48310S.0 | 400 | L | 1 |
| 48318P.0 | 500 | M | 1 |
| 48318P.0 | 500 | L | 1 |
| 48318P.0 | 500 | XL | 1 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | M | 2 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | M | 2 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | L | 2 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | L | 2 |
| 49318E.0 | 500 | XL | 1 |

Es decir, duplicando esas dos filas ya que tienen 2 como valor. Y si fueran 3 uds. triplicando las filas.

Algo engorroso pero que quizá podría funcionar sería declarar un contador y una cadena de texto que vaya concatenando los select de esas filas que tengan más de una unidad, pero no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo porque la consulta de la que ya estoy partiendo hay campos calculados: un *GROUP BY* por artículo, color y talla respectivamente, y el campo unidades es el resultado de un *COUNT(*)* dividido por otro campo de número entero que no estoy mostrando aquí.

Comment: Bienvenido Alejandro M. a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Pon tu consulta

Answer (score 1):

Es posible resolverlo desde `SQL` pero necesitas una tabla o vista que tenga las filas suficientes para repetir los datos que quieres, es decir si puedes tener hasta un valor de 100 unidades necesitarás un tabla con 100 filas al menos. Idealmente podría ser una tabla física, pero también como no tenemos necesidad de otra cosa más que de una fila con un número correlativo, podemos usar alguna vista del sistema para generarla.

Supongamos una tabla similar a tu ejemplo:

```
create table Ejemplo (
  Id       int,
  Cantidad int
)

insert into Ejemplo(Id, Cantidad) values (1, 1);
insert into Ejemplo(Id, Cantidad) values (2, 2);
insert into Ejemplo(Id, Cantidad) values (3, 3);

select *
       from Ejemplo

Id  Cantidad
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

---

Creo que se entiende la idea, del `id=1`, queremos una fila, del `2` dos filas, del `3` tres. Voy a usar `sysobjects` para obtener una buena cantidad de filas, y con `row_number()` voy a generar el numerador que me interesa. Luego simplemente se trataría de relacionar nuestra tabla con la del contador mediante un `left join`.

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (order by id) as n
         from sysobjects
)
select e.*
       from Ejemplo e
       left join cte c
          on e.Cantidad >= c.n

Id  Cantidad
1   1
2   2
2   2
3   3
3   3
3   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Con una estrategia similar, sin recurrir a tablas para las que puedas necesitar permisos, también puedes utilizar un `constructor con valores de tabla`, y `cross join`, para duplicar las filas

```
Create table Cod (art varchar(100), color int, Talla varchar(2), unidades smallint);
go
Insert into Cod (art, color, Talla, unidades)
values
('48310S.0',    400 ,'M',   1),
('48310S.0',    400 ,'L',   1),
('48318P.0',    500 ,'M',   1),
('48318P.0',    500 ,'L',   1),
('48318P.0',    500 ,'XL',  1),
('49318E.0',    500 ,'M',   2),
('49318E.0',    500 ,'L',   2),
('49318E.0',    500 ,'XL',  1);
go
```

Con la tabla creada, utilizas una tabla de expresión correlativa, para ir generando filas. La primera con 10 filas, 100, 10.000. Si necesitases más, solo tienes que implementar un c4 as ...

Luego numeras las filas obtenidas, que cruzarás con los datos. Aplicando una restricción para que las filas numeradas sean iguales o menores que las unidades.

```
;with c1 as (
    Select T.n From (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))T(n)
    ), c2 as 
    (Select b.n from c1 cross join c1 as b
    ), c3 as 
    (Select b.n from c2 cross join c2 as b
    ), nums as
    (Select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by c3.n) as rn
    From c3 
    )Select c.*
        from cod c
            cross join nums n
    where n.rn <= c.unidades
    order by c.art, c.Talla desc;
```

[image: Resultados]